# ASP.NET Identity (2.0) with Sharepoint

Tags: authentication, asp.net, claims-based-auth

I have been searching around for information about using the new ASP.NET Identity 2.0 with SharePoint, but not much luck...

Anyone succeeded setting it up?

Comment: This possibly touches on it: http://geeks.ms/blogs/lmanez/archive/2014/06/10/adding-windows-azure-active-directory-to-an-existing-asp-net-app.aspx